# C# embedded web server for Asp.Net

Tags: c#

I want to create an application where an device posts data to a certain address using JSON, and then a console application on that address prints out the posted data.

To do so, i thought it would be good to use a web server.

Is there any (open source) Asp.Net web servers that i can embed into my C# program to capture posted data to the web server?

Comment: All you need here is HttpListener

Comment: Thank you! Will look deeper into that, and come back and cry when i don't succeed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, you can create a small "web servlet" using a HTTPListener. [This article](http://www.wjunction.com/92-development-area/37895-%5Bc-%5D-tiny-web-server-snippet.html) demonstrates how to build one.

Comment: Do you know any good examples where i can print out posted data?

Comment: In the example I have linked, incoming requests are being logged into the console via Console.Write. The data from the client is received into 'HttpListenerResponse' object. You can modify the code and use the 'InputStream' property of 'HttpListenerResponse' object the get the contents of the request.